# Why was Araragi unable to understand Dramaturgie / Episode / Guillotine Cutter when they first met?

Tags: monogatari-series

Somewhere around forty minutes into *Kizumonogatari: Tekketsu-hen*, Araragi is set upon by the three exorcists who earlier dismembered Kiss-Shot: Dramaturgie, Episode, and Guillotine Cutter.

As they advance upon him, they speak to one another - but all we (the viewers) hear is a sort of guttural grumbling. Araragi presumably hears the same thing (non-speech sounds), given that he says something about trying to get them - as fellow human beings - to communicate with him rather than kill him.

What's the deal? On the one hand, this was certainly an incredibly stressful situation for Araragi, so he could well just have been on an adrenaline rush that was interfering with his hearing. But then again, this being *Monogatari*, it's not implausible that maybe they were speaking some sort of secret exorcist tongue.

Comment: Comment for now since I don't have the book handy to turn this into a referenced answer, but I believe that's just the film's way of representing their speaking a non-Japanese language (most likely English given their backgrounds) which Araragi doesn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He was speaking another language.

Going off the English version of the Kizumonogatari novel, page 81 shows that Dramaturgy spoke something that Araragi didn't understand. Vertical displayed this by just having a bunch of black boxes in quotations (dunno how Nisioisin did it in the Japanese novel, but I'm sure it's something similar). Page 82 starts with Guillotine Cutter reprimanding Dramaturgy for not using "the language of the land you're in", meaning that Dramaturgy was speaking a language other than Japanese.